# Prove that the largest eigenvalue (in terms of magnitude) of a non-symmetric matrix is real.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

> Let $A\in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$ be a non-symmetric matrix with
>   eigenvalues $\lambda _i$, $i=1,...,n$ satisfying $$\left | \lambda_1\right | >\left | \lambda _2\right |\geqslant \left | \lambda _3\right |\geqslant ...\geqslant \left | \lambda _n\right |.$$
>
> Prove that $\lambda _1$ is real.

Since A is a non-symmetric matrix and I wanted to tackle this problem using power iteration, I decomposed A as $$A=X\Lambda X^{-1}.$$

And I tried to solve it using some power iteration properties. But I have no idea how to proceed.

Edit: I made a mistake at the beginning. There should be a gap between the largest eigenvalue and other eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex eigenvalues of a real matrix come in conjugate pairs, as they are roots of the matrix's characteristic polynomial, which is real. If $\lambda_1$ is not real, its conjugate $\lambda_1^*$ is also an eigenvalue and has the same magnitude, meaning $\lambda_1$ does not have a *strictly* largest magnitude – contradiction. Hence $\lambda_1$ must be real.

Comment: i'm sorry i think i made a mistake in the description. there should be a gap between the largest eigenvalue and the rest eigenvalues

Comment: @Bella The proof is still simple. I have written up an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just one more question: what is the effect of "non-symmetric" property? Or actually we don't need this to prove that lambda 1 is real?

Comment: @Bella If the matrix is symmetric, all eigenvalues are automatically real, so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: oh true. Thanks